# Microsoft Outlook backup options

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, outlook-2010

I am trying to find ways to manage my client's Outlook... Their PST files tend to build up fairly quickly and I am looking for a solution for them to back up their emails. There used to be Outlook Backup? Is there anything similar out there?

I was wondering what are my options for backing up (set to automatically back up) Microsoft Outlook 2010 and beyond?

Comment: If you are not using Exchange, please remove the `outlook-web-app` tag (and possibly `Windows-server-2012-r2`, too). If you instead *are* using Exchange, please say so.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said whether your client is using Exchange, IMAP, POP3, or whatever, but I'm going to assume Not Exchange because you said PST (rather than OST).  I'm also going to assume that your users are putting their PSTs in relatively normal places in their profile directories (which isn't necessarily a safe assumption).

I'm going to recommend something that backs up the user's profile data automatically, like Crashplan Pro or a competitor (Carbonite, etc.).

If you're talking about Exchange--and the Windows Server 2012 R2 and OWA tags make me wonder--you're going to want to back up the server instead.  Any Exchange-aware backup software (including the free Windows Server Backup that came with your server) should do the trick.

If you absolutely insist on backing up PSTs and only PSTs, something like [this](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Back-up-Outlook-data-with-the-Microsoft-Outlook-Personal-Folders-Backup-tool-7ef27bac-6088-4f03-a9f7-34165d885883) might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with PST files is that they are very difficult to backup reliably. 
The easiest solution would probably be to use Office365 for email. That will store the email in the cloud. If there is more than 50gb of PST files then you may still get it all in to the cloud. PST files are incredibly inefficient - between two and three times the size of the data in Exchange (so inside Office365).